# How to show taking average decrease the uncertainty (noise)?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $g_{ki}(\xi_i) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector random variable at time stamp $k$ where we have the following:

1- $\mathbb{E}_{\xi_i}[g_{ki}(\xi_i)]=f_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\xi_i \sim D$

2- $\mathbb{E}_{\xi_i}[||g_{ki}(\xi_i)-f_k||^2] \leq \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sigma \neq 0$ and $\xi_i \sim D$

Let $G_k=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}g_{ki}(\xi_i)$ and $\xi_{[m]}=\{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_m\}$.

How can we show that $\mathbb{E}_{\xi[m]}[||G_k-f_k||^2] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{m}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic manipulation of norms gives
$$\|G_n - f_k\|^2 = \|\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m [g_{ki}-f_k]\|^2  \leq \frac{1}{m^2} \sum_{i=1}^m \|  g_{ki}-f_k\|^2.$$
Now, take expectations.

Comment: the last $m$ should be $m^2$.

Comment: Yes, good catch. Thanks.